# Laravel public_path() return C:\xampp\htdocs\ instead of http://localhost/

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to generate an url with the public_path() method, but I need the Htpp://localhost/... url, not the C:\xampp\htdocs... directory.

Im reading that I can modify the bootstrap/paths.php file but I dont know f it would be the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public_path()` returns just that, a *path* to a directory and not a *URL*.  If you want the URL to your site, try using `URL::to('/')`

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I dont know how I don't see it lol. Thanks.